# How to add and view image for next image in array by click next button

Tags: swift, xcode

I already create an array of image (imagelateral) and I want to implement the next button in the Xcode, but I cannot view the image in the array for the next image in an array

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
    let images: [UIImage] = [#imageLiteral(resourceName: "tub"),#imageLiteral(resourceName: "ball"),#imageLiteral(resourceName: "apple"),#imageLiteral(resourceName: "igloo"),#imageLiteral(resourceName: "frog")]
    var i : Int = 0
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    @IBAction func nextButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if(i+1 > images.count){
            i = 0
        }
        //self.imageView.image = [images images[i]:i]
        imageView.image = UIImage [images images[i]:i]
    }
}
```

it should show the next image in the array
example 1st: "tub" when clicking on the button next then show "ball"

Comment: `imageView.image = images[i]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is error in nextButton action. Your array give you UIImage, you don't need create new UIImage for set your imageView. Maybe work if you change nextButton action code with following code.

```
@IBAction func nextButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    i = (i+1)%images.count
    imageView.image = images[i]
}
```

Comment: Thx it work. One more thing, if i put input field how to make it equal to the image name in the array such as ( if inputfield == image name)

Answer (score 0):

Simply change the implementation of `nextButton(_:)` to,

```
@IBAction func nextButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    i = (i % images.count)
    imageView.image = images[i]
    i += 1
 }
```